# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm not really good at programming and I don't know what's happening in my codes, it works well before but now I get this error:

NullReferenceException was unhadled by user code.

Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's my code:

```
 void GetProfileInfo()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, EmailAddress FROM Users " +
            "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (data.Read())
        {
            txtFN.Text = data["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLN.Text = data["LastName"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = data["Address"].ToString();
            txtContact.Text = data["ContactNo"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = data["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: this line: cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();

Comment: Then Session["userid"] return null and you try to convert to a string.

Comment: It's time to learn some basic debugging skills.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i'm not really good at this. I want to learn though, what should I do :)

Comment: When you access things like `ViewState[...]` or `Session[....]` , you **MUST** check for `NULL` before doing anything else! So try something like `if (Session["userid"] != null) { ...... } ` - it's called *defensive programming* - never just blindly assume that there will be a valid value - **check for it!**

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check all occurrences where `Session["userid"]` is initialized,
then in order to avoid exception error you have to check this variable value whether is null or wrap the code with `try catch finally` blocks

Ex:

```
try
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, EmailAddress FROM Users " +
            "WHERE UserID=@UserID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();
        SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (data.Read())
        {
            txtFN.Text = data["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLN.Text = data["LastName"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = data["Address"].ToString();
            txtContact.Text = data["ContactNo"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = data["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    string message = e.Message;
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
finally
{
        con.Close();
}
```